# How to read the source code of a website with java

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am trying to write a web crawler in Java and so far it mostly works though i have problems with web sites that use JavaScript or PHP to dynamically get content, for example if i try to crawl a tumblr blog rather than getting the entire source code with links and everything i only get the CSS, and header information, this is because all the post information is gathered by JavaScript.

The code im using to get the source code from a web page is ...

```
public static String openURL( String url )
{
    String source = null;                                                                           
    String temp = "";                                                                       
    BufferedInputStream bis;                                                                        
    try
    {
        URL my_url = new URL(url);                                                          

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) my_url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);                  

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesread = 0;
        source = "";

        bytesread = bis.read(buffer);

        while( bytesread != -1 )
        {
            source += new String(buffer, 0, bytesread);
            bytesread = bis.read(buffer);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex ){}
    System.out.println(source);
    return source;                                                                              
}
```

Does any one how i can go about changing this so it will get dynamic content, any help would be much appreciated

Cheers Daniel

**EDIT :** sorry  guys while your answers are helpful, this project is more educational so i was trying to find a way to do it with out using third party API's

Comment: This is why delivering most content via javascript is bad for SEO, accessibility, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Generally web crawlers will see websites without the javascript having been processed. Web developers know this and so "good" websites can be read successfully without JS

IF you really really want to actually process the JS, (although your life is going to be a lot easier if you dont), you can use this tool: http://phantomjs.org/

I havent actually used it but it allows you to process the JS without using a browser..

Comment: In fact, it is a WebKit engine, the same engine you can find in Chrome. It's 'almost' a browser ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in Java, have a look at [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) which can deal with javascript, or [selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium) which can help you drive a real browser